# SQL EXCEPT: How to identify New Records VS Changed Records

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, except

Though my post is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038590/sql-check-table-for-new-rows), I still feel this is in a way different from that one.

I have 2 CSV files.

```
File A                                       File B
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name         | Country                     Name         | Country |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ferrari      | Italy                       Jaguar       | British |
| Mercedes     | Germany                     Chevrolet    | America |
| Jaguar       | British                     Bugatti      | Italy   |
| Nissan       | Japan                       Tata         | India   |
| Chevrolet    | USA                         Nissan       | Japan   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The above is used for illustration only. In general I have a lot more rows and columns in both of the files but their structure is same.

I was asked to perform a row level comparison of all the columns efficiently. So, instead of doing it programatically, I proposed using HSQLDB to 
`CREATE TEXT TABLE` and `SET SOURCE` with the files respectively and then do a `EXCEPT` operation between the files. I did code it and it works like a charm. Below is the SQL part that I coded to achieve the same.

```
CREATE TABLE COMPARE_TABLE AS (SELECT SRC.*, 'SRC-TGT' compare_order FROM TABLEA SRC EXCEPT SELECT TGT.*, 'SRC-TGT' compare_order FROM TABLEB TGT) WITH DATA;
INSERT INTO COMPARE_TABLE SELECT TGT.*, 'TGT-SRC' compare_order FROM TABLEB TGT EXCEPT SELECT SRC.*, 'TGT-SRC' compare_order FROM TABLEA SRC;
```

This gave me a result table which looks like the following (considering the sample data above):

**COMPARE TABLE**

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
|   Name     | Country  | Compare_order |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| Ferrari    | Italy    | SRC-TGT       |
| Mercedes   | Germany  | SRC-TGT       |
| Chevrolet  | USA      | SRC-TGT       |
| Chevrolet  | America  | TGT-SRC       |
| Bugatti    | Italy    | TGT-SRC       |
| Tata       | India    | TGT-SRC       |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

From here, I need to identify the reason for every row as to what did not match? Atleast, broadly, I would like to classify it into 3 categories:

- New at Source
- New at Target
- Value Changed (If possible, which column(s)?)

Finally, I want my table to look like the below:

**COMPARE_TABLE**

```
+------------+----------+---------------+------------------------+
|   Name     | Country  | Compare_order |     Failure_Reason     |
+------------+----------+---------------+------------------------+
| Ferrari    | Italy    | SRC-TGT       | New at Source          |
| Mercedes   | Germany  | SRC-TGT       | New at Source          |
| Chevrolet  | USA      | SRC-TGT       | Country value mismatch |
| Chevrolet  | America  | TGT-SRC       | Country value mismatch |
| Bugatti    | Italy    | TGT-SRC       | New at Target          |
| Tata       | India    | TGT-SRC       | New at Target          |
+------------+----------+---------------+------------------------+
```

How do I go about doing this? Can we even do this in SQL?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please format your question

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: @eggyal I dumped my final COMPARE_TABLE to mysql. And my next steps can also be in mysql. That is why.

Comment: MySQL does not support `except` (or `intersect`) So you will need to find a different approach there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the basic comparison as:

```
select name, country,
       (case when sum(which = 'src') > 0 and sum(which = 'tgt') then 'DROPPED'
             when sum(which = 'src') = 0 and sum(which = 'tgt') then 'NEW'
        end) as OP
from ((select 'src' as which, name, country
       from tableA
      ) union all
      (select 'tgt', name, country
       from tableB
      )
     ) ab
group by name, country;
```

But that doesn't give you column-by-column comparisons.  That is a bit more difficult.  Let me assume that `Name` is unique, so it can be used as a key.  The following does the comparison, but produces one row per name:

```
select name,
       (case when src.country is null then dest.country
             when tgt.country is null then tgt.country
             when src.country = tgt.country then dest.country
             else (src.country, '-->', tgt.country)
        end) as country,
       (case when src.country is null then 'new'
             when tgt.country is null then 'dropped'
             when src.country = tgt.country then 'same'
             else 'changed'
        end) as country,
from (select name from TableA union select name from TableB
     ) names left outer join
     TableA src
     on names.name = src.name left outer join
     TableB tgt
     on names.name = tgt.name;
```

Getting multiple rows for each name when the value in a column changes seems more difficult, although it too would be possible.

Comment: While I run the second query in Mysql, I am getting an error. ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @user3564168 . . . That means that `name` is not unique or a primary key in the two tables.  You have duplicate names in one or both tables.